# ISCSI Connector and Domain Name Migration

Tags: windows-server-2008, dell, iscsi

I have a Dell MD3000i that is connected to both of my Hyper V hosts. We recently went through a full domain migration from one domain to another.  The last AD server is one of the hyper v hosts connected to the MD3000i.  I was doing one last look around of everything on that server to verify I have everything and to record all the iSCSI settings before I reformat this machine. When going through all the ISCSI settings I noticed that everything in there is still using the old domain name.  I have no idea if this affects anything, since I'm about to decommission the last AD/DNS server of the old domain.  Will it just disconnect from the hosts? or does it not even care about what domain it's on?  I don't know much about this device or ISCSI.  I was barely able to get it connected in the first place.  I'm leaning towards it doesn't care about the domain since the initiator below shows that it's connected to server 2 on the old domain even though that machine is now on the new domain.

Plus we no longer have Dell Support so I can't call them for help on this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the initiator name is actually set in the configuration of the iSCSI initiator on the server (it's the last tab on the properties page ), so when you rename the server it should just remain the same, and you shouldn't have any issues.

The only thing you must make sure of is that you are not connecting to the array via a dns name that will no longer exist. You can do this by looking at the first tab of the iSCSI initiator properties on the windows machine.

You can get to the initiator by just typing "iSCSI" in the start menu.

There's a good microsoft guide http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2009/02/02/step-by-step-using-the-microsoft-iscsi-software-target-with-hyper-v-standalone-full-vhd.aspx that will help you if you get unstuck.

There's also a terse and slightly wordy technet document at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee338480(v=ws.10).aspx which contains most of the advanced options.

Comment: I will check out the articles.  I noticed that server1 updated to the new Initiator name on the server but not on the SAN management console.  That doesn't matter?  The first page I see discovered targets, and it doesn't seem to be any kind of dns name that I understand.  So I should be all set with that I think.